Dag with task based on condition
I need to create a dag with some tasks that should be executed daily, and one task that should be executed monthly on the 1st of each month:
task_1: should be executed daily
task_2: should be executed monthly, on the 1st of each month
task_3: should be executed dailly
So basically my dag should be either a simple sequence of tasks where task_2 should somehow be skipped if the execution_date is not the 1st of the month, or a dag with some branching that should execute task_1 and task_3 always, and task_2 only if the execution_date is the 1st of the month.
I've tried the short circuit decorator, and also a BranchPythonOperator using a Python function that returns the task depending on the date logic, however I don't seem to be able to do this. How can I accomplish this using TaskFlow API?
Thanks
@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2024,9,9),
    schedule_interval=None
)
def my_dag():

    task_1 = EmptyOperator(task_id='task_1')
    task_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id='task_2')
    task_3 = EmptyOperator(task_id='task_3')


    def monthly_branch(**kwargs):
        execution_date = kwargs['execution_date']
        if execution_date.day == 1:
            return 'task_2'
        elif execution_date.day > 1:
            return 'task_3'
        else:
            return None

    branch = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id = "branch",
        python_callable = monthly_branch 
    ) 


    task_1 >> branch
    branch >> task_2 >> task_3
    branch >> task_3 

my_dag()


If task_2 runs, do you still want to run task_3 or not?

Here I'm assuming that if task_2 runs, then task_3 should not run.
@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2024, 9, 9),
    schedule_interval=None
)
def my_dag():
    task_1 = EmptyOperator(task_id='task_1')
    task_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id='task_2')
    task_3 = EmptyOperator(task_id='task_3')

    @task.branch(task_id="branch")
    def monthly_branch(**context):
        execution_date = context['execution_date']
        if execution_date.day == 1:
            return "task_2"
        elif execution_date.day > 1:
            return "task_3"
        else:
            return None

    task_1 >> monthly_branch() >> (task_2, task_3)


my_dag()

